# « Dans un délai » ou « sous un délai » ?

Tags: sens, prépositions

> Dans un délai/Sous un délai

Je sais très bien que les deux s'utilisent couramment dans le langage quotidien par contre je n'arrive pas à voir la différence (probablement assez subtile) entre les deux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La formule correcte (admise par les dictionnaires consultés) est :

> Dans un délai.

Familièrement on utilise, souvent dans les relations commerciales

> Sous un délai.

Probablement un anglicisme (*Under deadline*) usité dans le monde des affaires, ou une résurgence d'un emploi juridique (Cf. : le commentaire de Gilles).

Il n'y a donc pas de différence de principe.

Cependant,

- la formulation 'correcte' donne une notion de limite d'exécution,
- l'utilisation de *sous* laisse entendre une contrainte comminatoire pouvant mettre en jeu les tribunaux.

Comment: C'est vrai que « dans un délai » est la formule habituelle, mais je ne vois pas en quoi « sous un délai » serait un anglicisme. On la trouve de façon nettement minoritaire dans le vocabulaire juridique déjà (ou encore ?) au début du XIXe siècle.

Comment: N'y a-t-il pas une différence du type « dans un délai » = « à la fin du délai » et « sous un délai » = « avant la fin du délai » ? Par exemple : « Vous recevrez vos résultats dans un délai de 24 h. » et « Vous devrez vous présenter à la préfecture sous un délai de cinq jours. » À noter que je ne trouve pas de référence sur la signification exacte de chacune des deux expressions, donc c'est assez intuitif.

Comment: @Chop Les exemples avec *sous* étant inexistants dans les dictionnaires compulsés, et, Gilles l'ayant relevé dans le vocabulaire juridique... disons que la probabilité que l'intuition fasse état d'un usage augmente. Mais il est vrai que je l'ai toujours entendu dans la sphère 'judiciairo-réglementaire' (comme votre exemple le signale, si la personne ne se présente pas sous quinze jours, il n'est pas certain qu'il lui arrive quelque chose d'agréable) et donc lié à une contrainte administrative.

Comment: Je ne peux toujours pas m'améliorer quand les votes négatifs sont sans explication : le fond de la question ne porte-t-il pas sur les nuances d'utilisation ?

Comment: @cl-r Je pense que votre réponse était exacte. Merci. En tout cas, ce n'était pas moi qui vous avais donné un vote négatif.

Comment: @optimalcontrol Je m'en doutais :) . Vous avez déjà accepté et valorisé ma réponse comme 'meilleur réponse' !

Comment: @Chop On voit bien la différence de sens si on enlève "un délai de": "Vous recevrez vos résultats dans 24h" / "Vous recevrez vos résultats sous 24h". Mais elle me semble moins nette avec "un délai de".